# Why routerLink is not working when everything is configured correctly

Tags: angular, typescript

Part of view where `routerLink` is located

```
<p><a routerLink="/registration" class="nav-link">Зарегистрироваться</a></p>
```

My `app.module`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component';
import { TestStartComponent } from './components/test-start.component';
import { TestListComponent } from './components/test-list.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './components/registration.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: TestListComponent },
    { path: 'teststart/:id', component: TestStartComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' },
    { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, [CommonModule], FormsModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
    declarations: [AppComponent, TestListComponent, TestStartComponent, RegistrationComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

My `RegistrationComponent`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    templateUrl: '../views/registration.component.html',
    providers: [UserService]
})

export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private userService: UserService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("sas");
    }
```

My registration.component.html

```
<p>sas</p>
```

When I click on the link - nothing happened. Another routerLinks are working correctly.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: @Sajeetharan When I click on the link - nothing happened.

Comment: Did you try by adding the property pathMatch: 'full', to the following route: { path: '', component: TestListComponent }? So the route would be { path: '', component: TestListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }.

Comment: @ArmandoPerez I have another routerLink in test-list.component.html and it is working

Comment: @ArmandoPerez And I try `{ path: '', component: TestListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }.` and this doesn't help.

Comment: Leave the pathMatch as it is, and also, move this route { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' } to be the last one. Let me know your results please.

Comment: I will add an answer so it helps others when they visit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, add pathMatch: 'full' to the following route:

```
{ path: '', component: TestListComponent }
```

And move the following route to the end:

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
```

So the end result would be:

```
    { path: '', component: TestListComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'teststart/:id', component: TestStartComponent },
    { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
```

According to the Angular official documentation:

> The path-match strategy 'full' matches against the entire URL. It is important to do this when redirecting empty-path routes. Otherwise, because an empty path is a prefix of any URL, the router would apply the redirect even when navigating to the redirect destination, creating an endless loop.

For the wildcard, the official docs say:

> A URL string that uses router matching notation. Can be a wild card (**) that matches any URL (see Usage Notes below). Default is "/" (the root path).

Finally, take into consideration that the order in which you specify your routes is important. Think it as if the Angular engine is going one by one from top to bottom scanning each one to see which one matches the requested url.